# Embedded Script (Tasks List API Sample) throws "'Tasks' is not defined" error (works when run in Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-tasks-api

When attempting to embed Google’s sample provided for the Tasks API ([code found here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks#sample_application)) into Google's Classic Sites I get the dreaded “script.google.com refused to connect”. The logging error is `"Tasks" is not defined at getTasksLists(simpleTasks:15)`. Details:
[image: Tasks error details]

When I embed this same script into Google's New Sites, the UI does show, but the drop-down continues to display “Loading…” (see screenshot below), however if I click on the link provided to view my “Google Tasks” it does go to my Tasks in a new window. 
[image: Tasks UI]

This runs successfully directly from Google Apps Scripts, showing the “Authorization required” pop-up and allowing me to sign in and accept permissions.  However, when embedded into both New and Classic sites, it does not request any authorization.

Steps I've taken embedding into **Classic** Sites (where it needs to be):

1. *from URL provided above*: copied code exactly as is into a new Scripts project (nothing altered or added).
2. *from Scripts*: deployed it as a Web App, copied the URL provided (the code provided in the link above has not been altered in any way by me)
3. *from Scripts*: enabled Tasks API though Resources, Advanced Google Services
4. *from Sites*: edit page, Insert Apps Script, pasted URL (i.e. https//script.google.com/macros/s/...5Ym41qn/exec)

Other things I've tried:

- from Sites: embedding URL as an iFrame gadget (same results)
- solution given here: [How to add Google Drive Scripts project into Google Sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738782/how-to-add-google-drive-scripts-project-into-google-sites) (same results)
- days of research into Google's documentation (for Sites, APIs, Scripts, Cloud Platform, you name it)... (various results but nothing productive)

I am very new to working with Sites, Scripts, the Cloud Platform, etc. so apologies if I am missing some obvious steps here.  Any guidance would be truly appreciated!

Leora

**UPDATE [03-21-19]:**

I was able to get this working finally!  Although not posting as answer just yet as I haven't figured out the exact change that was brought success.

I thought it was by changing the option within Sites' *Publish* / *Deploy as web app...* / *Execute the app as:* from 'ME' to 'USER' (after doing that it worked), but when I changed it back to make sure that was it, it still worked?

I will play around with it more this weekend and update when I come to a definitive solution.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to help me out here, and if anyone does have any guidance on what's happening here, I'd love to know.

Comment: I've been messing with Tasks lately and got their snippet to work without problems (although I didn't embed it). Are you sure that you published your script before you embedded it? does it work on the test URL? Are you on a personal gmail account or a work one?

Comment: I did publish my script before embedding it, it does work in the test URL via scripts, and I am working through a work G Suite Enterprise account.